# Get rows from file1 which are not in file2 based

Tags: r

How can I get rows from file1 which are not present in file2 based on matching column particularly (DataName and GeneName) values from two files? I have tried function intersect and subset but I am not sure how to give two columns for matching.

lets say I have two data frames

file1

```
geneName  DataName count
 A4GALT    data1   34
 ABAT      data1   34 
 ABCA1     data1   60
 AASS      data2   12 
 ZWINT     data2   39
 ZYG11A    data2   23
 ZYX       data1   1
 ......
```

file2

```
 geneName  DataName
 A4GALT    data1
 ZWINT     data2    
 ABAT      data1
```

The resulted data.frame would be

```
 geneName  DataName  log
 ABCA1     data1     60
 AASS      data2     12
 ZYG11A    data2     23
 ZYX       data1      1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could try `anti_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df2, by=c('geneName', 'DataName'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Or try base R:

```
 file1[!(file1$geneName %in% file2$geneName &
                file1$DataName %in% file2$DataName),]
 #    geneName DataName count
 #3    ABCA1    data1    60
 #4     AASS    data2    12
 #6   ZYG11A    data2    23
 #7      ZYX    data1     1
```

Comment: Perhaps `file1[!(file1$geneName %in% file2$geneName & file1$DataName %in% file2$DataName),]`

Comment: You might be right, something is wrong. It seemed quite logical to me though. Let me find a solution and fix this.

Comment: Oh, you did it for me. Thanks. Good thing I tend to check the page before hitting accept on edits.